# Programatically trigger TouchableOpacity.onPress

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have a use case, where after a file upload I want to open lightbox wrapped inside `<TouchableOpacity>`

here is my code.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{marginRight: ms(10), borderRadius: ms(10), overflow: 'hidden'}}>
    <Lightbox>
        <FastImage
            style={{width: ms(75), height: ms(75), borderRadius: ms(10)}}
            source={{uri: this.props.image.path}}
        />
    </Lightbox>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Lightbox does not have any event to trigger open programatically, here is the lighbox I am using https://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox

My only option seem to trigger `TouchableOpacity.onPress` programatically after file upload is done, tried using ref the following way.

`TouchableOpacity ref={component => this.touchable = component}` with `this.touchable.props.onPress();` this gives me an error saying undefined is not an object, when I did `console.log(this.touchable)` I noticed it is not empty, however when I did `console.log(this.touchable.props)` it says undefined, perhaps syntax is changed which does not seem to be documented.

Is there any way to trigger onPress programatically?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting a ref to Lightbox component and trigger "ref.open();" Open is their internal onPress.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try :

```js
ref={(touchable) => this._touchable = touchable}
```

```js
this._touchable.touchableHandlePress()  //this?
```

Comment: [DOC](https://git.artos-hosting.de/hbrs/react-native/commit/debca6d24f558d985b3d83d54a470628357e0d96#fa1173dc26f27a014e68bee539ce6aad3be2486f_110_108)

Comment: Not sure what is happening, it says `touchableHandlePress` is not a function :-(

Comment: It looks still there in new version, but maybe need something. [DOC](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Touchable/Touchable.js#L108)

Comment: I'm not sure if change component to touchable could work? It's seems just call the function could work before